# How to change a material card view theme style programmatically?

Tags: kotlin

I have an app which displays a list of train services.
Depending on whether a train service stops or passes, I want the `MaterialCardView` to have a different style (ie a different background color).
I also want these background colors to be different for night mode as well, so here is my current theme structure:

**Theme.xml**

```
<style name = "serviceCall" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="materialCardViewStyle">@style/daycall</item>
</style>
<style name = "servicePass" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="materialCardViewStyle">@style/daypass</item>
</style>
```

**Theme.xml (Night)**

```
<style name = "serviceCall" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="materialCardViewStyle">@style/nightcall</item>
</style>
<style name = "servicePass" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="materialCardViewStyle">@style/nightpass</item>
</style>
```

A `MaterialCardView` will use either `serviceCall` or `servicePass` depending on whether a train stops. And both of these inherits either a daycall/daypass or nightcall/nightpass depending on whether the user's device is in battery saver/night mode or not.

**The material cards are displayed in a RecyclerView**
I have been attempting to use something along the lines of the following (pseudocode), but the background defaults to a dark purple colour.

```
if(train stops here){
       holder.materialcardview.setCardBackgroundColor(R.style.serviceCall)
}else{
       holder.materialcardview.setCardBackgroundColor(R.style.servicePass)

}
```

Comment: That is because you are changing the backgroundColor of the card view using style which is not applicable thus no changes occur .  Make use of drawables for the same  or create a custom view extending material layout and pass params for the attribute set the style you want to set (Complex Method)

Comment: Thanks Karunesh, drawables would be ideal - is it possible to set drawables in style.xml? IE set s background drawable for a specific material card, in style.xml (so I can reference it in theme.xml and have separate one for day / night ?